# Determine the size of chart bar in flutter

Tags: api, flutter, date, charts, size

I am trying to create a chart that displays the data that came from the api that is supposed to be like this image[image]
as for the date and the size of the columns, no matter how many data are coming

**I have two problems**:
1- I don't know Make the widget flexible so that the column always appears the same size
2- I don’t know. Make the date the same as what is needed. It is displayed in the same form in the API
[image] how can I fix it

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more about the date thing?

Comment: the date in api is String like ''2020-03-11'' and I want to change it to ''11/3'' , DateFormate takes only time not string

Comment: .now I solved date problem

Answer (score 1):

For making a widget flexible and appear the same size you can use BoxConstraints by adding Container or SizedBox as parent widget and defining height and width.

Comment: I tried both and did not reach the required.the ruselt in picture by using sizedBox